# How to have iTerm 2 change color based on the current directory

Tags: iterm2

I'd like iTerm2 to change colors based on the current directory, for different client projects. How do I do that?

Comment: Not really a complete answer, but you might be interested in https://iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html and https://iterm2.com/documentation-badges.html